# this в Java. Помогите пожалуйста понять. Уместно ли использовать this?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста. Уместно ли использовать слово this в данном случае??

Я создал класс часы У класса есть поле `VoltageIstochnika`
Далее я создал метод, который написан ниже. Уместно ли там использования слова this??

```
public void changeBattery () {
        System.out.println("VoltIst"+this.VoltageIstochnika);// Какой правильный вариант? Этот?
        System.out.println("VoltIst"+VoltageIstochnika);// Или этот?
        if(VoltageIstochnika<=2.8) {
            this.VoltageIstochnika = 3.35F; // нужно ли здесь слово this?
            this.SostoyanieIstochnika = 100;// а здесь?
            System.out.println("Батарея на часах заменена на новую.\n");
            System.out.println("VoltIst"+this.VoltageIstochnika);
            System.out.println("VoltIst"+VoltageIstochnika);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Батарея в нормальном состоянии и не требует замены.");
        }
```

============================================================
(В мэйн создал два объекта )

```
 BatteryClock BatClock1 = new BatteryClock();
    BatteryClock BatClock2 = new BatteryClock();
    BatClock1.VoltageIstochnika = 2.4F;
    BatClock2.VoltageIstochnika = 2.9F;
    BatClock1.changeBattery();
    BatClock2.changeBattery();
```

Comment: Обычно this пишут когда возникает неоднозначность между другой такой же переменной, например переданной как аргумент в метод. А так - this - не обязательно писать. Ещё главное - выбрать для себя стиль и всегда придерживаться. Захотите - можете всегда писать, но только всегда и везде.......... Кстати, в разных компаниях могут быть требования к этому разные

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо большое. Значит за ошибку это не считается и в принципе разницы нет.

Answer (score 4):

Конкретно в вашем случае **this** писать не обязательно (и я редко где видел, чтобы это ключевое слово использовалось именно в таких случаях).

P.s.
**this** обязательно нужно использовать тогда, когда название поля объекта и параметра метода (или конструктора, что по существу одно и то же) совпадают.

Пример:

```
class SomeClass
{
  private String name;

  public SomeClass(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

в вашем случае this не обязательно. если хотите то можете оставить - это ни на что не влияет. this это просто указатель для компилятора и результат будет одинаков, что с ним, что без. как описал @Sergey Chernikov this обязательно нужно использовать если имена объектов, методов и тп одинаковы.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

this это как Ссылка на элементы которые находятся в области видимости класса.
Используется:

- когда перекрывает область видимости

  ```
    Box(double width, double height, double depth) {
        this.width = width; //одинаковые названия переменных (вне метода и внутри) 
    }
  ```
- когда нужно вызвать из конструктора другой конструктор. Но важно помнить что в конструкторе вызов this() может находиться только в первой строчке конструктора:

  ```
    public Toy(String name, int cost, int age) {
        this(name, cost); //используем другой конструктор
        this.age = age; 
    }

    public Toy(String name, int cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
  ```